# remove columns with duplicated column names only if row values are a certain string

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, drop

I need to remove columns that have duplicated names, but only remove the duplicate that has all row values as 'nan' (as a string, not NaN). The example data and expected output are below. Thanks so much!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'a':[0,0,0,'nan'], 'b':['nan','nan','nan','nan'], 'c':['nan','nan','nan','nan'], 'd':[1,'nan',0,2]})

df = df.rename(columns = {'a':'a','b':'a', 'c':'b', 'd':'b'})

    id  a   a   b   b
0   1   0   nan nan 1
1   2   0   nan nan nan
2   3   0   nan nan 0
3   4   nan nan nan 2
```

expected output

```
    id  a   b
0   1   0   1
1   2   0   nan
2   3   0   0
3   4   nan 2
```

Comment: `.dropna(how='all', axis='columns')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is, if you want to keep columns which are empty, but unique. If not you can solve it in a single line: `df1 = df.dropna(how='all', axis='columns')` If you want to keep them you can drop them and then re-create them because they are essentially just empty after all.

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'a':[0,0,0,np.nan], 'b':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 'c':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 'd':[1,np.nan,0,2], 'e':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
df = df.rename(columns = {'a':'a','b':'a', 'c':'b', 'd':'b'})
```

Code:

```
df1 = df.dropna(how='all', axis='columns').copy()
df1[list(df.columns.difference(df1.columns))] = np.nan
```

Out:

```
#    id    a    b   e
# 0   1  0.0  1.0 NaN
# 1   2  0.0  NaN NaN
# 2   3  0.0  0.0 NaN
# 3   4  NaN  2.0 NaN
```